# Convert large GeoTIFF files to GeoPandas -National Hurricane Center Storm Surge Risk Maps

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geopandas

For a given latitude/longitude location (for example, for a home or commercial property), I need to find out the storm surge at that location given a hurrican category.

The data is available in interactive form here: https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/203f772571cb48b1b8b50fdcc3272e2c/page/Category-4/

The same data is available as zipped GeoTIFF files at https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/nationalsurge/#data.  There is one .tif file for each category, and several accompanying files for each.

I am able to load the data using the code below, but unable to do anything after as the array size is too large.
[image]
Both `data.plot()` and `data.values` give me memory errors, even for the smallest of the files I get

> "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 32.1 GiB for an array with shape (1, 136550, 252315) and data type uint8".

My laptop has 32GB RAM.

Is there a way to convert these files to GeoPandas format so I could simply use 'contains' to determine the property's expected storm surge?

Comment: You don't need to read the entire raster in, nor do you need to create a geodataframe from it. Just use the [dataset.sample](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.sample) method. Here's an example https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/geopandas_rasterio_sample.html

Comment: Thank you for this - it works.  Let me post final results once I am done.  THanks a lot for helping a newcomer to GIS data.

Comment: When I use `dataset.sample` method, I need to use GPS coordinates per my TIFF file's CRS.  However I am a returned a "no value" (255) unless the coordinates are exactly as coded in the file.  For example:

`[int(x) for x in data.sample([(-74.018, 40.765)])]` returns a value of 5, but the same for `(-74.017, 40.765)` returns a missing value equivalent 255.  But these points are 100 feet away, and colored the same on the map equivalent. <br><br>

Since I will provide any known coordinates, I would like the closest available point's value to be returned.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, the doc state "*Values are from the nearest pixel. They are not interpolated.*" so if the point falls in a pixel, you should get a value.  If not, can you ask a new question with code to demonstrate, example point coordinates and raster details (extent, rows, cols and CRS) so we can try to replicate.

Comment: Thank you for this pointer as well.  Yes, I am getting a value - there was a mistake in what I reported earlier (40.765, -74.017 was incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get to what I was trying to do.  Many thanks to user2856 for the pointers.  Here is the code I used

```
# Get lat and long from python using GeoPy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-test-user-agent")
location = geolocator.geocode("33 Peck Slip, new york ny")

print(location.address)
print((location.longitude, location.latitude))

coords = [(location.longitude, location.latitude)]

# Use Cat1 SLOSH file from https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/nationalsurge/#data.
import rasterio
data = rasterio.open(r"us_Category1_MOM_Inundation_HIGH.tif")

print("\n Storm surge in feet:")
print([int(x) for x in data.sample(coords)])
```

[image]

Comment: Great self-answer! I suggest you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).